# Terraform - how to see the URL being accessed when 'terraform apply' command is run

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform script to provision AWS resources on AWS. This is the script.
To run this script, i need to open up the firewall between our domain and AWS. How do I know which url this script accesses on AWS to provision the resources? I was hoping to see that URL in the output of terraform apply command.

Terraform apply - to run this script

```
    provider "aws" {
       region     = "us-east-2"
       access_key = "validaccesskey"
       secret_key = "validsecretkey"
       max_retries = 1
    }

    resource "aws_vpc" "AWS_VPC"{

          cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
          tags = {
          Name = "Main VPC"
    }
  }

       resource "aws_instance" "my_web_server" {
             ami           = "ami-00843a337042b9b8b"
             instance_type = "t2.micro"

             tags = {
                 Name="DEV server"
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the environment variable `TF_LOG=TRACE`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/environment-variables.html . That way A LOT of logs will be generated, the URLs will be visible in there.

You will probably need to whitelist basically anything [`*.amazonaws.com`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) or mutliple `service.amazonaws.com`.

---

E.g. for

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" { name = "testing" }
```

after running `terraform init` once we can run

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="asd" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="test" TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply
```

and see that there is a request towards `sts.amazonaws.com`:

```
2021-03-16T16:33:17.417+0100 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.32.0_x5: 2021/03/16 16:33:17 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: sts.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.37.24 (go1.16; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.14.8 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/dev (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws)
Content-Length: 43
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=asd/20210316/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=d1215314fb3271dc87ca655071b179cad44c73c882bddb6a0e2bbef91514a00e
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20210316T153317Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2021-03-16T16:33:17.417+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an output variable around the URL: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html

This way, after you run `terraform apply`, the output value is shown afterwards in the end, and if you wish to toggle the value in the future, you can just run `terraform output [options] [NAME]`.

Comment: And how does that help to know what services / urls terraform talks to while deploying infrastructure?

Comment: This is on the assumption that the URL is stored somewhere within files generated after `terraform apply`. If that's not the case, the above would not work.